Habit Tracker Recurrence Implementation
I am creating a Habit Tracker app in flutter
and there two screens in App
Home Screen
In this there is a Horizontal list of dates, a tab bar to add different kind of tasks and a floating button that will navigate to another screen where we will define the Name, Description/Note, and Recurrence of habit
Habit Adding Screen
There we can add habit by giving it the name, description and recurrence (when/On which dates it should be displayed)
the Recurrence options that i have given to it are:
Once (the habit will show once on the date that the user selected)
EveryDay (the habit will show Everday from the date created)
Select In Week (the Habit will show every week on the days that the user selected)
Select In Month (the habit will show every month on the dates that the user selected)
Select In Year (the habit will show every year on the dates that user selected)
Select In Range (the user will select a range of dates on which the habit will be displayed)
I have also created an Sqflite database service that stores the habit and sends it to Home screen
Problem
Now the Problem is that when i add habit it is showing in the console (i have added print statements to show it) but the Home screen doesn't show any habit?
I asked ChatGPT and also look some websites and youtube videos but didn't find any solution to this, i just want My app to work with this Recurrence functionality, if you have any other idea of how i can add this type of functionality, You can tell me also
Console Output for the problem added and set to show only once:
Performing hot restart...
Syncing files to device TECNO LD7...
Restarted application in 2,939ms.
I/flutter (31388): Selected Date: 2024-08-20 00:00:00.000
I/flutter (31388): Items Map: {2024-08-20 09:55:27.613067: []}
I/flutter (31388): Fetched map: {id: 1724128708944, name: My Habit, description: This is my first Habit, recurrence: Once, dates: ["2024-08-20T00:00:00.000"]}
I/flutter (31388): Map in fromMap: {id: 1724128708944, name: My Habit, description: This is my first Habit, recurrence: Once, dates: ["2024-08-20T00:00:00.000"]}
I/flutter (31388): Loaded habits: [Instance of 'Habit']
I/flutter (31388): Selected Date: 2024-08-20 00:00:00.000
I/flutter (31388): Items Map: {2024-08-20 00:00:00.000: [Instance of 'Habit']}
I/flutter (31388): Selected Date: 2024-08-20 00:00:00.000
I/flutter (31388): Items Map: {2024-08-20 00:00:00.000: [Instance of 'Habit']}

You can clearly see the problem is added to the console but its not showing on the screen

After you update your state, are you calling setState?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I can't go further than guessing the issue without reading the code block, but it seems likely that the issue is related to not updating the state after the fetch is completed.
If so, I highly recommend Interactivity blog post provided by Flutter team.
